# Modules in node.js not working

Tags: node.js, module

I have 3 files, one simple .html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>meh server</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <script src = "index.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The 'server.js':

```
module.exports.proto = function() {
        alert("Working function");
    }
};
```

And the 'index.js':

```
 var server = require('./server');

 server.proto();
```

All in the same folder. I have node.js installed on my PC and typed on the windows cmd ''npm install nodejs'' on the folder of the 3 files. I can't receive the alert from server.js and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Node.js is a runtime, there is no DOM. So 'alert' is not defined in node.

Secondly, you need to run a node program by executing the node binary & passing file name as command line argument, like

```
node your_file_name.js
```

For getting response both in command line & in browser you need to do the following:

## Command Line:

file: server.js

```
module.exports.proto  =  function () {
    console.log("Working function");
}
```

file: index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
server.proto();
```

now run following command in command line:

```
node index.js
```

you will see your desired output in command line.

## Browser:

file: server.js

```
module.exports.proto  =  function () {
    return "Working function";
}
```

file: index.js

```
var server = require("./server");

var httpServer = require("http");
httpServer.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(server.proto());
    response.end();  
}).
listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server listening on 3000");
});
```

now run following command in command line:

```
node index.js
```

you will see following in the command line:

```
server listening on 3000
```

now go to browser & hit the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

You will see your desired output in your browser.

*** For more info I would recommend to look into 'http' API of node.
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Thanks. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have syntax error in your server.js file.

```
module.exports.proto = function() {
   alert("Working function");
};
```

Secondly, you dont have 'alert' function in node. You can write console.log instead

```
 module.exports.proto = function() {
       console.log("Working function");
    };
```

Then run index.js from command prompt

```
node index.js
```

You can see the message "Working function" in the command prompt.

Opening your html file in your browser wont work the same way. You really need to understand node :)

**EDIT:**
*index.js*

```
var server = require('./server');

 var http = require('http');
 fs = require('fs');

 http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     server.proto();
     fs.readFile('index.html', 'binary', function(err, file) {
      if(err) {
         res.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
         res.write(err + "\n");
         res.end();
         return;
      }

      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      res.write(file, "binary");
      res.end();
      });
 }).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started");
 });
```

Now if you run index.js from command prompt go to localhost:3000 in your browser, you can see it working the way you actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**Oh!** `alert` is not anything recognized by `node.js`, It is part of browser.

Instead of using `alert` you should be logging your message, It also seems you either have not copied full code or it's really a *syntax error*, so fix it as:

```
module.exports.proto = function() {
    console.log("Working function");
}
```

Now you can use your IDE to run `index.js` or goto any shell and shoot `node index`, it will run node code.

**Secondly** If you want your `node.js` server to send or open `html` file in browser [Follow This Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files)

Answer (score 1):

Well, installing Node.js is a start, but it seems like you are confused about what node.js is. Node is the runtime. Yes it is built on top of V8 (same JavaScript VM in Google Chrome), but there is no DOM, none of the Browser API's, and absolutely no need for a Browser. So, `alert` doesn't exist in Node. I recommend getting familiar with the [API docs](https://nodejs.org).

As previously answered, you run a node program by executing the `node` binary and passing a file as an argument (there is a repl, and other options) just like you would run a python, or ruby program. In your case:

```
node index.js
```